# Taking the constant out in derivatives. How does it work and how do I notice that I am able to do it?

Tags: calculus

I am currently trying to solve the derivative to this function:
$$
f(x)= \frac{x^3+9x+8}{2x^2}
$$

by using the quotient rule **only** and after simplifying to the best of my ability I get:

**EDIT:**

---

$$\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^3+9x+8)\cdot2x^2-(x^3+9x+8)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(2x^2)}{(2x^2)^2} \Leftrightarrow $$

$$
\frac{(3x^2+9)\cdot2x^2-(x^3+9x+8)\cdot2(2x)}{2x^4}
$$

$$
\frac{6x^4+18x^2-4x^4+36^2+32x}{2x^4}
$$

$$
\frac{2x^4+54x^2+32x}{2x^4}
$$
I just realized that there is a plus sign after $2x^4$ in the numerator, so that I can't just cancel them. Although, I have figured it out now. :)

---

$$
54x^2+32x
$$

However, when I input the function into [Symbolabs calculator](https://www.symbolab.com/) I get the following from finding the derivative:
$$
\frac{x^3-9x-16}{2x^3}
$$

And when taking a look at the steps (since I made a mistake), I could see that [they took the constant out before even applying the quotient rule](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdx%7D%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B3%7D%2B9x%2B8%7D%7B2x%5E%7B2%7D%7D%5Cright)?or=input).

How do I acknowledge this? I don't understand how it's possible to "randomly" take out one of the constants and why it would be from the denominator as well. I understand every step **but** that.

Thanks in advance! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math SE. It'd be better for us if you show the full process of how you received your answer.

Comment: Just as an FYI, this is way easier to do if you distribute the denominator first, becomes nothing but powers of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time an expression, abc, can be rewritten as (a)(bc), where a doesn't contain any variables, "a" is a constant. Here,
$$
\frac{x^3+9x+8}{2x^2}
$$
Can be rewritten and retains the same mathematical value as:
$$
\frac 1 2 \frac{x^3+9x+8}{x^2}
$$

Therefore, $\frac 1 2$ is a constant that can be pulled out.